# interrogate a Ruby array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to group people by age in Ruby. I have their date of birth, and a method which returns their age in years. So a solution like this works.

```
case
when (0..15).cover?(age_years)
  'child'
when (16..24).cover?(age_years)
  '16 to 24'
when (25..34).cover?(age_years)
  '25 to 34'
when (35..44).cover?(age_years)
  '35 to 44'
when (45..54).cover?(age_years)
  '45 to 54'
when (55..64).cover?(age_years)
  '55 to 64'
when age_years > 64
  'really old'
else
  'unknown'
end
```

However, I am trying to learn Ruby and am looking for a more elegant solution. I thought about putting the age_ranges into an array of hashes like this...

```
age_ranges = [{ name: 'child', min_age: 0, max_age: 15 },
              { name: '16 to 24', min_age: 16, max_age: 24 }]
```

but am at a loss as to how to interrogate this data to return the correct name where the age_years is within the appropriate ranges, or even a range like this

```
age_ranges = [{ name: 'child', age_range: '0..15' },
              { name: '16 to 24', age_range: '16..24' }]
```

which looks neater but I have no idea if I have written gibberish as I don't know how to extract the name when the age years matches.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

Now that you have an map of age names and ranges (note I used *range*, not string as a value of `age_range`), you want to search the `age_ranges` array of hashes for such, which value of `age_range` includes the age:

```
def age_ranges
  [
    { name: 'child',    age_range: 0..15 },
    { name: '16 to 24', age_range: 16..24 }
  ]
end

def find_age(age)
  age_ranges.find { |hash| hash[:age_range].include?(age) }[:name]
end

find_age(12)
#=> "child"
find_age(17)
#=> "16 to 24"
```

Note, that `[:name]` will fail if `find` returns `nil` (meaning, no matches found).

To overcome it either add an infinite range as a last one in the array (I'd prefer this one, because it is simpler):

```
def age_ranges
  [
    { name: 'child',    age_range: 0..15 },
    { name: '16 to 24', age_range: 16..24 },
    { name: 'unknown',  age_range: 25..Float::INFINITY }
  ]
end
```

Or handle it while fetching the age in the `find_age` method:

```
def find_age(age)
  age_ranges.each_with_object('unknown') { |hash, _| break hash[:name] if hash[:age_range].include?(age) }
end
```

Also, make sure to handle the negative numbers passed to the method (since `age_ranges` do not cover negatives):

```
def find_age(age)
  return 'Age can not be less than 0' if age.negative?
  age_ranges.find { |hash| hash[:age_range].include?(age) }[:name]
end
```

P.S. After all these "note/make sure" I want to say that @mudasobwa's answer is the simplest way to go about it :)

Comment: `age_ranges.each_with_object('unknown') { |a, _| break a[:name] if a[:age_range] === age }` handles the `'unknown'` case, while your code does not.

Comment: In general, `find`/`detect` is not applicable as a surrogate for `case` unless you have an explicit `|| ELSE_VARIANT`.

Comment: @mudasobwa actually after a glance at your code decided to add a note about the out of range age passed to method. Will edit in a moment, thanks

Comment: `each_with_object` still handles negatives, though :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Range#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) triple equal directly, as it is supposed to be used:

```
case age_years
when 0..15 then 'child'
when 16..24 then '16 to 24'
when 25..34 then '25 to 34'
when 35..44 then '35 to 44'
when 45..54 then '45 to 54'
when 55..64 then '55 to 64'
when 64..Float::INFINITY then 'really old' # or when 64.method(:<).to_proc
else 'unknown'
end
```

---

To make `case` to accept floats, one should use triple-dot ranges:

```
case age_years
when 0...16 then 'child'
when 16...25 then '16 to 24'
when 25...35 then '25 to 34'
when 35...45 then '35 to 44'
when 45...55 then '45 to 54'
when 55...64 then '55 to 64'
when 64..Float::INFINITY then 'really old' # or when 64.method(:<).to_proc
else 'unknown'
end
```

Comment: `Proc#===` is useful too: `when -> (a) { a > 64 }`

Comment: Hah, I asked this very same question [ages ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531662/125816) :)

Comment: Or put a `when nil then 'unknown'` at the top and use `else` to handle the "above 64" part.

Comment: @Stefan `64.method(:<).to_proc` :) Also, `when nil` is wrong, due to negatives.

Comment: @Stefan What about 15.5?

Comment: @EricDuminil Good catch. I have updated an answer to handle floats.

Comment: 64.5 should be really old.

Comment: @EricDuminil and it is, why?

Comment: @EricDuminil age values are usually given in whole years. In the odd case of fractional years you could just say `case age_years.to_i` (or `floor` / `ceil` / `round`, whatever fits) but I doubt that you'll ever need it.

Comment: Who knows? Depending on the input, it could also from a duration in seconds which has been converted to float years.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it, to avoid code repetition between 16 and 64 :

```
def age_range(age, offset=4, span=10, lowest_age=16)
  i    = ((age-offset-1)/span).to_i
  min  = [i*span+offset+1, lowest_age].max
  max  = (i+1)*span + offset
  "#{min} to #{max}"
end

def age_description(age)
  case age
    when 0...16 then 'child'
    when 16..64 then age_range(age)
    when 64..999 then 'really old'
    else 'unknown'
  end
end

(0..99).each do |age|
  puts "%s (%s)" % [age_description(age), age]
end
```

It outputs :

```
child (0)
child (1)
child (2)
child (3)
child (4)
child (5)
child (6)
child (7)
child (8)
child (9)
child (10)
child (11)
child (12)
child (13)
child (14)
child (15)
16 to 24 (16)
16 to 24 (17)
16 to 24 (18)
16 to 24 (19)
16 to 24 (20)
16 to 24 (21)
16 to 24 (22)
16 to 24 (23)
16 to 24 (24)
25 to 34 (25)
25 to 34 (26)
25 to 34 (27)
25 to 34 (28)
25 to 34 (29)
25 to 34 (30)
25 to 34 (31)
25 to 34 (32)
25 to 34 (33)
25 to 34 (34)
35 to 44 (35)
...
```

As a bonus, it also works with Floats (e.g. 15.9 and 16.0).

Comment: Why do you prohibit people to live more than 999 years?!

Comment: Why do you prohibit people to live more than Aleph-naught?! :)

Comment: @mudasobwa On a more serious note, returning `unknown` for people older than 1000 years could help finding bugs, for example parsing `31/12/99` as `31st of december 0099` and returning `age` as 1918.